# "only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" when I use the sin function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm sorry if the solution to this error is trivial, but I've extensively reserchead with no luck. Every answer on the internet says that this error appears when you try to use an array as a scalar, but I can't understand how to apply this information here. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from math import e, sin
from scipy import misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return x-e**-x

a = 0
b = 1
pas = 0.1

x = np.arange(a, b+pas, pas)
plt.plot(x, f(x), 'r-')
plt.show()
```

And it works with no problem, until I try to use the *sin* function in some way:

```
def f(x):
    return x-e**-x+sin(x)
```

In this case, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "a.py", line 14, in <module>
> plt.plot(x, f(x), 'r-')   File "a.py", line 7, in f
> return 10*x-9*(e**-x)+int(sin(x)) TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

I can't understand why it thinks it's not a scalar. I tried to calculate f(0), f(0.5), f(1) and the output is always a scalar. What's happening here? What's special about the sin function?

Comment: `x` is an `array` (from `arange`).  Your code passes that to `math.sin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> def f(x):
> return x-e**-x

> And it works with no problem

This is because: to `numpy`, `**` is a [unary ufunc](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.03-computation-on-arrays-ufuncs.html#Exploring-NumPy%27s-UFuncs) that corresponds to `np.power`. So `numpy` can execute vectorize operations with it i.e. you can pass a vector to the function.

> until I try to use the sin function in some way:

Here, however, you are using `math.sin` which is *unknown* to `numpy` - it's a "regular" function to it and no vectorization can happen there*. Since [`math.sin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.sin) is expecting a single Python scalar, you get the error.

To fix these, I'd suggest you use `numpy`'s sine function i.e. `np.sin` (and also `np.exp` in lieu of `math.e`). It will be "known" to numpy and will be vectorized right away.

> I tried to calculate f(0), f(0.5), f(1) and the output is always a scalar

There you are passing Python scalars so everyone is happy :)

---

*: there is `np.vectorize` and you can wrap a regular function (e.g. `math.sin` here) with it to vectorize it but it's essentially a for loop so it is not at all preferable when an already-vectorized version exists i.e. `np.sin`.

Answer (score 2):

When you USE your `f(x)` for plotting, `x` is indeed an array, not a scalar.

Because, for some reason I cannot understand, you've imported `sin` and `exp` from `math` and not from `numpy`, the `sin(x)` that you use in the definition of `f(x)` expects a scalar.

The Python runtime tries to cast your `x` (`x =np.arange(a, b+pas, pas)`) to a scalar float, but a type error is raised

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```